# How to make bracket safe from async exception?

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, exception, concurrency

Every Haskell article about exceptions repeats simple pattern: Use bracket function to allocate/release resources and you will be safe.

I have a concern, because I tested its behavior and detected that the thread can get async exception while working inside release section.

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.Concurrent

main = do
  tid <- forkIO myThread
  threadDelay 100000
  throwTo tid StackOverflow
  threadDelay 1000000

myThread = 
  bracket 
    (putStrLn "NEW")
    (\() -> threadDelay 500000 >> putStrLn "CLEAN")
    (\() -> putStrLn "USE")
```

In the snippet above "CLEAN" is not printed due async exception - so resource leaks! How it can be claimed safe?

I don't know everything it must be a reason.
To make it safe as I see it I need to wrap every cleaning inside mask. It looks clumsy.

Comment: @Cubic apparently you can't do anything safely in the presence of async exceptions. One might be thrown just before your cleanup function runs, and skip the entire cleanup function

Comment: Related: https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2014-September/023675.html https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2m6swm/making_bracket_uninterruptible_during_cleanup/

Comment: The short answer use `unliftio`, it already does the right thing for all exception handling functions:  https://github.com/fpco/unliftio/blob/13ace879fcd578c15adf7ff2cba383462e600707/unliftio/src/UnliftIO/Exception.hs#L292

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To make it safe as I see it I need to wrap every cleaning inside mask.

Unfortunately, I think the answer is exactly that. If you have cleanup actions that *must* be run for resource safety, *and* you want to maintain resource safety with async exceptions, then you *must* use an uninterruptible mask during cleanup.

It’s similar to restricting yourself to signal-safe functions inside Unix/Linux signal handlers or exception-safe functions in C++ destructors, except the criterion here is “uninterruptible”, whether inherent to the functions you call, or by masking (maybe simpler to get right).

Alternatively, you can use the [`bracket`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-0.2.13.1/docs/UnliftIO-Exception.html#v:bracket) from the `unliftio` package, which uses uninterruptible masking in its cleanup handler. (Unrelated to your question, this package provides the [`MonadUnliftIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-core-0.2.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Unlift.html#t:MonadUnliftIO) class for lifting `IO` operations through stateless wrappers; it’s a restricted alternative to the more complex [`MonadBaseControl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.2.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl) from `monad-control`, which handles stateful wrappers over any base monad.)